# Basic DC Fan Controller

Tags: automotive, fan

I have been tasked with retrofitting some small fans to an old car, to help move heated air into the footwells. Being a computer-type, I immediately bought some standard computer cooling fans.

The fans are DC, and the only rating information is 8-12V.

It was my hope that a basic potential divider with knobbed potentiometer would provide a voltage-based fan control:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhyFMa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I only ask because any search for "Fan Control" leads to pulse-width-modulation. Is it possible to control fan speed using this basic circuit above?

Comment: That's pretty wasteful, your resistors will waste at least 12/3 = 4 amps! and produce at least 4x12 = 48W of heat. You'll need pretty big high-wattage resistors in order not to start a fire in the footwell. Unless you are using the resistors to heat up the footwell you should perhaps be looking for PWM control. Your potentiometer won't provide any control unless you connect the wiper to one end.

Comment: Rgr on the miswiring of the potentiometer. Is it not possible to scale up the resistances to still provide the 8-12 range from a 12V source while wasting less energy?

Comment: Note I have edited the schematic, and removed the second resistor. My understanding of this goes back to school days, so I may have made things worse.

Comment: I'm afraid that *is* worse, a 1 Ohm potentiometer will produce 144 Watts of heat at 12 V. It may be hard to find a vendor who sells a 1 Ohm 150W potentiometer. I'd look for PWM solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, maybe I'll stick with a nice simple off switch.

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/kew0xv447/image.png
I drew a circuit with schmitt trigger hex inverter oscillator and mosfet motor driver.. But I'm not sure it will do the job or not..

Comment: I'd want to be sure PC fans are up to the job, they are fundamentally a different design to most HVAC blowers and there's a good reason for that. HVAC fans have to move air against some resistance and with some force through ducting, vents, against shutoff flaps, etc., PC cooling fans don't and as such have far less power behind them.

Comment: Since you have several fans, simply switch more fans on to increase the cooling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PWM is used because it wastes much less heat than "linear" methods like that shown in your schematic. A TO-92 voltage regulator and a DIL8 microcontroller is all you need to read the voltage from a 10kohm pot and then generate a PWM signal to put through a power MOSFET on the low side of the fans. You could even substitute a 555 and associated passives, but the MCU will give you better control.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSBVGh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>